# pterodactyl server status page

Tags: javascript, html, css, api

i'm trying to make a pterodactyl status page
that shows the server name, server owner, server status (offline, online, suspended), server disk space, server ram space, server cpu space.

and i have en error that i could not fix
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://181.214.197.131/api/application/servers' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value ''.

here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Server Status</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Server Status</h1>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Server Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Disk Space</th>
        <th>RAM</th>
        <th>CPU</th>
        <th>Owner</th>
        <th>Type</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <div id="server-data">
    </div>
  </table>

  <script>
    const api_url = "http://181.214.197.131/api/application/servers";
    const api_key = "Bearer ptla_88AGkvZFV9JeBviAoEdUKwSKmyr5WAED5kGVeKk2CxT";

    $(document).ready(function () {
      $.ajax({
        url: api_url,
        headers: { "Authorization": api_key },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
            const server = data.data[i];
            const server_id = server.id;
            const server_name = server.attributes.name;
            const server_status = server.attributes.status;
            const server_disk_space = server.attributes.limits.disk;
            const server_ram = server.attributes.limits.memory;
            const server_cpu = server.attributes.limits.cpu;
            const server_owner = server.attributes.user.username;
            const server_type = server.attributes.feature_limits.allocations;

            $('#server-data').append(`
          <tr>
            <td>${server_name}</td>
            <td>${server_status}</td>
            <td>${server_disk_space}</td>
            <td>${server_ram}</td>
            <td>${server_cpu}</td>
            <td>${server_owner}</td>
            <td>${server_type}</td>
          </tr>
        `);
          }
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

i tried to make a pterodactyl status page
that shows the server name, server owner, server status (offline, online, suspended), server disk space, server ram space, server cpu space.

and got error
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://181.214.197.131/api/application/servers' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value ''.